# Alphabetically Sort C++

Tags: c++, parsing, alphabetical-sort

I have a list of video game characters that are organized in a certain way.
I want to be able to take their names only from the list and sort it alphabetically.

The list is formatted by:

```
Last Name, First Name, Game, Relase Date, Score, Developer
```

The list is:

```
Snake, Solid, Metal Gear Solid, 9/3/1998, 94, Konami
Drake, Nathan, Uncharted, 11/19/2007, 90, Naughty Dog
Guy, Doom, Doom, 5/13/1993, 95, iD
```

The output I want is:

```
Drake, Nathan
Guy, Doom
Snake, Solid
```

I can print out there names only in the order in which they are in the text file. How do I compare the last names, then print out the full names?

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream inFile;

class Characher{
private:
    string first;
    string last;
public:
    Character(){};

    void getLast(){
    if(inFile.is_open()){
        getline(inFile, last,',');
    } else {
    cout<<"Hmm.."<<endl;
        }
    }

    void getFirst(){
    if(inFile.is_open()){
        getline(inFile, first,',');
    } else {
    cout<<"No First Name here..."<<endl;
        }
    }

    void printLast(){
    cout<<last<<",";
    }

    void printFirst(){
    cout<<first<<endl;
    }
};

class Dev{
private:
    string Developer;
public:
    Dev(){};//null constructor

    void printDeveloper(){
    cout<<"Developer: "<<Developer<<endl;
    }

    void getDeveloper(){
    if(inFile.is_open()){
        getline(inFile, Developer);
    } else {
    cout<<"Nothing here..."<<endl;
    }
    }
};
class Game{
private:
    string game;
public:
    Game(){};

    void getGameName(){
    if(inFile.is_open()){
       getline(inFile, game,',');
       } else{
       cout<<"What game was they frum?"<<endl;
       }
    }

    void printGame(){
    cout<<"Game: "<<game;
    }

};

class RelDate_And_Score{
private:
    string ReleaseDate;
    string Score;
public:
    RelDate_And_Score(){};

    void GetRelDate(){
    if(inFile.is_open()){
        getline(inFile, ReleaseDate, ',');
    } else{
    cout<<"Could not find Release Date"<<endl;}
    }

    void getScore(){
    if(inFile.is_open()){
        getline(inFile, Score, ',');
    } else{
    cout<<"Could not find Score"<<endl;}
    }

    void PrintDate(){
    cout<<"Release Date: "<<ReleaseDate<<" | ";}

    void PrintScore(){
        cout<<"Score: "<<Score<<endl;}

};

int main(){
    inFile.open("Games.dat");

    Dev d;
    Characher c;
    RelDate_And_Score r;
    Game g;

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        c.getLast();
        c.getFirst();
        g.getGameName();
        r.GetRelDate();
        r.getScore();
        d.getDeveloper();
        c.printLast();
        c.printFirst();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)? Define `operator<` on your objects or write a `Compare` function that can compare them.

Comment: You can't change the order in the file, so you need a copy in memory: create a map, add every line to the map and take the name as key. A loop over the map will show them sorted

Comment: Your design with different classes for character, game, date and so on, with each class opening and accessing a global file object, is more complicated than needed and will probably not work, as those classes will interfere by reading the same line. It would be easier to have one class instance per line, with string members for character, game, ..., put instances of those classes in a vector (do not use the number 3 in your loop, keep it flexible), and then use `std::sort` on the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I see you work directly with the file for each method (getLast() etc). This is not the best way to do it, as accessing the file is costly and less efficient.

You should construct a representation of the file in memory: Start with representing each row as a Character class such as:

```
class Character
{
    public:
    Character(const string & firstname, const string & secondname, const string & game, const string & releasedate, const string & score, const string & developer)
    :
    m_firstname(firstname), m_secondname(secondname), m_game(game), m_releasedate(releasedate), m_score(score), m_developer(developer)
    {}

    private:

    string m_firstname, m_secondname, m_game, m_releasedate, m_score, m_developer;
};
```

Open the file, read each row, construct a Character using the parsed strings (split by commas).

As tadman proposed in a comment, you can use the [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) method to order the Character by names. Implement the operator< in the Character class such as:

```
class Character
{
    //...
    bool operator<(const Character & c)
    {
        return m_firstname < c.m_firstname;
    }
    //...
};
```

So you can use the std::sort on your `vector<Character> m_characters`

```
std::sort(m_characters.begin(), m_characters.end());
```